# Why does \n and (String)System.getProperty("line.separator"); act differently?

Tags: java, string, io, system, stringbuilder

My program takes a input of a text file that has words each separated by a newline and my program takes it and deals with the data, and then I am required to output to a new file whilst keeping the console output.

Now I am wondering why when I append "\n" to my stringBuilder that it prints it out as it were to have a new line in the console, but in the file output, it doesn't take it as a new line and just puts all the words in one line.

When I use newLine, then only does it give a new line in both my console output and my output file. Why is that? What does (String)System.getProperty("line.separator") do that causes this?

```
String newLine = (String)System.getProperty("line.separator");

 try{
     BufferedReader fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

     stringBuilder.append(newLine);
     while((s = fileIn.readLine()) != null){
        stringBuilder.append(s);
        stringBuilder.append(newLine);//using newLine, 
     }
        String a = stringBuilder.toString();

     if(s== null){
        fileIn.close();
     }
```

Comment: Because on some systems (think OSX or Windows), `\n` is not the line separator?

Comment: you should use `System.lineSeparator()` and no need to cast the result to `String`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because on some systems (Linux/Unix) a new line is defined as `\n` while on others (Windows) it is `\r\n`. Depending on the software reading the text, it may chose to adhere to this or be more "forgiving" recognizing either or even `\r` individually.

Relevant Wikipedia text (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline):

> Systems based on ASCII or a compatible character set use either LF
>   (Line feed, '\n', 0x0A, 10 in decimal) or CR (Carriage return, '\r',
>   0x0D, 13 in decimal) individually, or CR followed by LF (CR+LF,
>   '\r\n', 0x0D0A)

This is also why you can retrieve the system-defined line separater from the `System` class as you did, instead of, for example, having it be some constant in the `String` class.

Comment: This answer is wholly incorrect. On Windows systems, the newline String is \r\n and on Unix systems it is \n (LF or ASCII char 10).

Comment: @DarrellTeague Thank you for catching the error. I have edited the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

`System.getProperty("line.separator")` is different from `"\n"` in that the former returns the OS line separator (not always `\n`).  `\n` is just a line feed, and when you open your output file in a program that does not interpret `\n` as a new line (say, Notepad on Windows) you won't see that new line.