# Difference between System.getProperty("line.separator"); and "\n"?

Tags: java, javafx-8, file-handling

While developing GUI with Java FX, I seem to get different results with  `System.getProperty("line.separator");` and `"\n"` during writing to a file or getting data from internet.  What basically is the difference?

Comment: There are several strongly related questions. I'm not sure whether one perfectly qualifies as a duplicate, but at least, your question is basically answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33505978/3182664

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`System.getProperty("line.separator")` returns the OS dependent line separator.

On Windows it returns `"\r\n"`, on Unix `"\n"`. So if you want to generate a file with line endings for the current operating systems use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` or write using a `PrintWriter`.

Comment: So, which do you think is better ? Suggest please.

Comment: @TilakMadichetti depends on the use case. If you want line breaks for your current OS use the first form. What do you want to write?

Comment: I want to write huge list of words into a file and one line gap b/w each word.

Comment: @TilakMadichetti if you generate the linebreak with `\n` and open the file on windows in a bad editor (say notepad), the linebreaks will not be displayed. But again good editors will be able to handle unix and windows linebreaks...

Answer (score 14):

on the Windows platform, System.getProperty("line.separator") is "\r\n",
"\n" (Linux and MacOS X), "\r" (MacOS 9 and older)

Comment: You get my upvote for mentioning older `\r` line separators !

Answer (score 7):

`System.getProperty("line.separator")` is platform dependent:

- "\n" on UNIX style machines
- "\r\n" on Windows machines

Whereas "\n" is only "\n".

Answer (score 4):

«\n» is the line separator for most operating systems such as Linux/Unix. To ensure the compatibility with any operating system, query this value with System.getproperty