# If we're told to use the system property line.separator instead of hard-coding \n, why does my code work on Windows?

Tags: java, cross-platform, system-properties

We all read something like this:

> use the System.getProperty(String) method to refer to items which
>   depend on the system, such as line terminators and path separators.

The quote is copied from this [web site.](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=38)

I hard-coded an `\n`, and the code below works on my Windows machine as expected.

```
package sample;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello\nworld");
    };

}
```

The output is:

```
hello
world
```

I thought the Java compiler replaced `\n` with `\r\n` silently. So I downloaded JD GUI, opened the JAR file, and saw `Hello\nworld`. Can anybody give me an example where `\n` doesn't work and `System.getProperty("line.separator")` does?

Comment: Write your Sting into a file with the Java program, open it with Notepad and you will see what the Problem is

Comment: @Jens, you're right. It looks like Command Prompt substitutes the correct line endings, and Notepad doesn't. So if you convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864999/if-were-told-to-use-the-system-property-line-separator-instead-of-hard-coding#comment74765878_43864999):
It looks like Command Prompt substitutes the correct line endings, and Notepad doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There are different line separators, depends on the OS. Read this thread:
[What is the difference between \r and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n)

Excerpt of if:

> More importantly, Unix tends to use \n as a line separator; Windows tends to use \r\n as a line separator and Macs (up to OS 9) used to use \r as the line separator. (Mac OS X is Unix-y, so uses  \n instead; there may be some compatibility situations where \r is used instead though.)

Comment: This is a possible duplicate question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796136/difference-between-system-getpropertyline-separator-and-n