# How to make table structure in csv file when using org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file)?

Tags: jmeter

I used Webdriver sampler and write selenium -Javascript. Now I used org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new java.io.File('result.csv'), 'myresultdata', 'UTF-8', true) function to write a file . I want to save a tabular data (column & row-wise means one column header and multiple row data) in that file using writeStringToFile() function.is there any other way to write in a csv or xlsx file? How we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `myresultdata` should have the "table structure" inside it, i.e. columns should be separated by commas (or other [separators](https://kb.blackbaud.com/knowledgebase/Article/75155)) and there should be a [line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796136/difference-between-system-getpropertyline-separator-and-n) in the end of every "row"

```
var newline = java.lang.System.getProperty('line.separator')
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new java.io.File('result.csv'), 'header1,header2' + newline, 'UTF-8', true)
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new java.io.File('result.csv'), 'value1,value2' + newline, 'UTF-8', true)
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new java.io.File('result.csv'), 'value3,value4', 'UTF-8', true)
```

it will generate the `result.csv` file looking like:

```
header1,header2
value1,value2
value3,value4
```

which can be imported into Excel or equivalent without any issues

Also you might want to reconsider your approach, in case of running your test with > 1 thread (virtual user) you will run into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when 2 or more threads will be concurrently writing into the same file so it makes sense to migrate to [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) listener

Comment: can I used variable which is already used in my WebDriver sampler script?Actually here I want to calculate pagination time for 5 users for 10,50,100 pages so how we declare variable in user.properties file and also Flexible File Writer?