# Using useDelimiter to scan multiple words in a line

Tags: java, delimiter

I am currently learning Java(beginner) and while using Scanner, specifically .next() property, I was reading an article that used this `sc.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`
to scan multiple strings(words) in a single line separated by a space, I dont really get what the `System.getProperty("line.separator")` do(the input given was for example "Hanu babbar",  here without that line it only printed out "Hanu" but with that it printed out whole "Hanu Babbar"). I read about useDelimiter and how its used to separate out content from a string but I dont really know the rest so would appreciate the help.
Here's the code snippet from the article

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
System.out.println("Please enter your name");
String name = sc.next();
System.out.println("Hello " + name);
sc.close();
```

Comment: Hello. Please don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)) but as formatted text. Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: Related: [Difference between System.getProperty("line.separator"); and "\n"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36796136), [How do I get a platform-independent new line character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/207947)

Answer (score 0):

From the [JavaDocs of `Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#default-delimiter):

> The default whitespace delimiter used by a scanner is as recognized by `Character.isWhitespace()`.

This is the reason why your `sc.next()` without the expicitly set delimiter returns each word extra instead of the whole line. `Character.isWhitespace` recognizes also other characters than newline as whitespace, it's [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)) well.